# Problema en Raspberry Pi ImportError: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi

Ejecutando un código de python me sale el siguiente error al llamar a scipy.stats

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 305, in _custom_import
module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 641, in <module>
from ._ufuncs import *
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 305, in _custom_import
module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
ImportError: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

He encontrado que el problema puede ser en algún paquete. En concreto ejecutando el siguiente comando

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

Obtengo lo siguiente en la consola de la Raspberry

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes adicionales:
  gfortran gfortran-6 libatlas-dev libatlas3-base libblas-dev libgfortran-6-dev
Paquetes sugeridos:
  gfortran-doc gfortran-6-doc libgfortran3-dbg libcoarrays-dev libblas-doc liblapack-doc liblapack-dev liblapack-doc-man
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  gfortran gfortran-6 libatlas-base-dev libatlas-dev libatlas3-base libblas-dev libgfortran-6-dev
0 actualizados, 7 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 2 no actualizados.
Se necesita descargar 10,2 MB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 48,4 MB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] S
Des:1 http://ftp.cica.es/mirrors/Linux/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libgfortran-6-dev armhf 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1 [199 kB]
Des:2 http://ftp.cica.es/mirrors/Linux/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf gfortran-6 armhf 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1 [5.421 kB]
Des:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf gfortran armhf 4:6.3.0-4 [1.352 B]
Des:4 http://ftp.cica.es/mirrors/Linux/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libatlas3-base armhf 3.10.3-1+rpi1 [1.920 kB]
Des:5 http://ftp.cica.es/mirrors/Linux/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libblas-dev armhf 3.7.0-2 [114 kB]
Des:6 http://ftp.cica.es/mirrors/Linux/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libatlas-dev armhf 3.10.3-1+rpi1 [65,9 kB]
Des:7 http://ftp.cica.es/mirrors/Linux/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libatlas-base-dev armhf 3.10.3-1+rpi1 [2.528 kB]
Descargados 10,2 MB en 1s (5.422 kB/s)       
Seleccionando el paquete libgfortran-6-dev:armhf previamente no seleccionado.
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python-apt-common', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libnpth0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `bind9-host', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libdom4j-java', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libenchant1c2a:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python-simplejson', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libjs-jquery', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libxaw7:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `cpp', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `perl-modules-5.24', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libsbc1:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `strace', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libmpeg2-4:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libnettle6:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3-pantilthat', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3-gpiozero', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libatasmart4:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libk5crypto3:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `scratch2', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libss2:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libdns162:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python-urllib3', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `firmware-realtek', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `rpi-chromium-mods', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libavdevice57:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libid3tag0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `hyphen-en-gb', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `lp-solve', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `fontconfig-config', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `geany', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libxcb-xfixes0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libgtk2.0-common', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `lxplug-ptbatt', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3-flask', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libmatroska6v5:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libasyncns0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libpam-systemd:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libip4tc0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libcdio13:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `piwiz', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libstdc++-6-dev:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libconfig-inifiles-perl', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `nuscratch', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libwacom-common', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libjs-underscore', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3-mote', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libaudiofile1:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python-pianohat', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `lxplug-network', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `iso-codes', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libncursesw5:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libzbar0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libisorelax-java', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `rename', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libarchive13:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `i2c-tools', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `install-info', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3-rtimulib', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: error fatal irrecuperable, abortando:
 no se puede abrir el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3-rpi.gpio': La estructura necesita una limpieza
sh: 1: /usr/bin/gdbus: Structure needs cleaning
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

He probado alguna otra cosa, pero francamente, no se cómo arreglar esto